# Avoid self penetration/intersection of parts of a plant during manipulation

Tags: modeling, physics

I have a model of strawberry plant (see bellow).

(a) I want to be able to do 2 things without all the different parts of the plant intersect/penetrate each other or surrounding objects:

1. deform the plant - e.g. tilt it to one side, press it down or pull it up, etc.. (I would prefer to be able to manipulate the plant as a whole AND part by part, if possible).
2. press the plant against a wall a bit and get a realistic deformation (without intersections).

I need a static picture, no need for animation.

(b) I'm wondering how those models are created in the first place without the leaves, flowers, fruits penetrating each other?

I can't upload the strawberry model because it is copyrighted, but maybe you can show me how to do the above mentioned 2 things (deform and press against a wall) on this free plant model (by [GerhardH](https://blendswap.com/profile/109404)):

[image]

[image]

Comment: sweet...and what did you try so far?

Comment: @Chris - I tried to separate the model into subobjects (stems, leaves, fruits, flowers), but I don't manage to move them around manually without them hitting other subobjects... Probably there is a technique to do so, but I'm not aware of it...

Comment: Note: The model in the attached blend file has duplicated vertices. You need to merge them (key M, Merge By Distance) or the cloth simulation will not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know an easier way for this, but maybe some professionals here have a better solution ;)

One way you could go is this (but it is pretty tedious and lot of work):

Give your fruit, leaves etc. a cloth modifier with some pressure + collision + pin group.
You have to play around a bit with the settings so that it fits your needs.

Then you can get something like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you! I have attached an example model to my question - maybe you can show this effect on it?